# SupportMapFragment on DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I need to embed a`SupportMapFragment`in a`Dialog`. This is the best I could think of:

```
public class SupportMapFragmentDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private final SupportMapFragment fragment;

    public SupportMapFragmentDialog() {
        fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        setTargetFragment(fragment, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
            final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return fragment.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public SupportMapFragment getFragment() {
        return fragment;
    }

}
```

However, when I call this:

```
final SupportMapFragmentDialog dialog = new SupportMapFragmentDialog();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Historico");
```

I get this:

[image]

What can I do to see the map on the Dialog?

The app has another `SupportMapFragment` that is working wonders, so it doesn't have anything to do with the configuration.

Comment: Is there anything wrong shown in the logcat?

Comment: Nope. Nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ended up using`MapView`in a regular`Dialog`instead of`SupportMapFragment`

This is my code:

```
final Historico h = adapter.getItem(arg2 - 1);
if (mv.getParent() != null) {
    ((ViewGroup) mv.getParent()).removeView(mv);
}
final Dialog d = new Dialog(HistorialScreen.this);
d.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
d.setContentView(mv);
mv.getMap().clear();
mv.getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(h.getPosicion(), 17));
final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
options.position(h.getPosicion());
mv.getMap().addMarker(options);
d.show();
```

And it works as intended.

Answer (score 12):

You can show a map fragment in a dialog by this

```
public class DialogMapFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private SupportMapFragment fragment;

    public DialogMapFragment() {
        fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapdialog, container, false);
        getDialog().setTitle("");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.mapView, fragment).commit();

        return view;
    }



    public SupportMapFragment getFragment() {
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

R.layout.mapdialog:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```