# Placing SupportMapFragment on DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to add SupportMapFragment on DialogFragment, but it return `error inflating class fragment`. I cannot figure it out why its returned `error inflating class fragment`. I think the method I use is correct. I need to extends from DialogFragment because i want show map in dialog.

I have followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16978233/1533670), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19725995/1533670) too,  and no one can solve my problem.

Somebody could help me?

Thanks.

Here is my DialogFragment :

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

/* For widget */
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Button;

/* Image Downloader Library */
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/* For string formater */
import com.yai.app.math.support.StringFormater;

/* For object */
import com.yai.app.object.support.Property;
import com.yai.app.object.support.User;

/* For context */
import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;

/* For map */
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class DialogFragmentReadAdvertisement extends DialogFragment{
        private Property propertyData;
    private User userData;
    private Context contextData;

    private GoogleMap mapDetail;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        propertyData = MainActivity.activeProperty;
        userData = MainActivity.activeUser;
        contextData = App.getContext();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_read_advertisement, container, false);

        mapDetail = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_data))
                .getMap();

        mapDetail.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions().position(propertyData.getLocation())
        );

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                            .target(propertyData.getLocation())
                                            .zoom(19)
                                            .tilt(0)
                                            .bearing(0)
                                            .build();

        mapDetail.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is my xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- One view for ScrollView -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Line 13 bellow -->
        <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map_data"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is my LogCat :

```
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.DialogFragmentReadAdvertisement.onCreateView(DialogFragmentReadAdvertisement.java:55)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:310)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.DialogFragmentReadAdvertisement.onCreateView(DialogFragmentReadAdvertisement.java:55)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #13: Duplicate id 0x7f05009e, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
07-14 16:28:46.291: E/AndroidRuntime(28121):    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

Change this..

```
mapDetail = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_data))
                .getMap();
```

to

```
mapDetail = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_data))
                .getMap();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it still `error inflating class fragment on line 13`

Answer (score 6):

I was facing problem while adding GoogleMapFragment inside DialogFragment and I have solved it as

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapDialog);
    } else {
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapDialog);
    }
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

> Override onDestroy() as

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (null != supportMapFragment)
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove(supportMapFragment)
                .commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, fully functional  !

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else comes along with a similar issue...

To answer your original question, the InflateException  (*Error inflating class fragment*) has occurred because nested fragments - i.e., your SupportMapFragment inside a DialogFragment - may not be inflated from static XML layouts.

See this note from the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments):

> **Note**: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a `<fragment>`.
> Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment programmatically.

So your layout.xml should contain a `<FrameLayout.../>` for your SupportMapFragment instead of the explicit `<fragment.../>`, then you'll just add the map fragment via code versus layout inflation.

And since ***nested fragments*** must be managed via a FragmentManager from [getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()),
you'll want to change the existing [getFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()) call
when setting up your FragmentTransaction for adding the map fragment programmatically (don't forget to commit!).

For a great example, take another look at the `R.layout.mapdialog` XML example and associated handling shown in the [second SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963019/supportmapfragment-on-dialogfragment/19725995#19725995)
you originally included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your XML

```
<!-- Line 13 bellow -->
        <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map_data"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

instead of class use android:name like the one below

```
<!-- Line 13 bellow -->
        <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map_data"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```